# Running Nexus Repository Manager on Kubernetes behind nginx-ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, proxy, nexus

I deployed Nexus Repository Manager into my k8s cluster using this chart:

```
helm install nexus-repo sonatype/nexus-repository-manager
```

And basically its working, i configured ingress for it like following:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nexus-repository-manager-1657876136
  namespace: nexus
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nexus-repository-manager-1657876136
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nexus-repository-manager
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 3.40.1
    helm.sh/chart: nexus-repository-manager-40.1.0
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nexus-repository-manager-1657876136
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: nexus
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: '0'
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: XXXXXX
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: XXXXXXX
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nexus-repository-manager-1657876136
                port:
                  number: 8081
```

But when accessing it via ingress adress and even logging as admin i cannot see Admin Panel, it works fine when i access Nexus using Kubernetes port forward of the local service:

Over ingress:
[image]

Local:
[image]

I found something on Sonatype page:

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/planning-your-implementation/run-behind-a-reverse-proxy?_ga=2.172248675.1526664279.1657877367-424333102.1657629011

And i tried to add the following to the ingress-nginx configmap so its injected to ingress's nginx.conf:

```
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: 'true'
  proxy-send-timeout: '120'
  proxy-read-timeout: '300'
  proxy-buffering: 'off'
  proxy-request-buffering: 'off'
  upstream-keepalive-timeout: '60'
  proxy-body-size: '1G'
  proxy-set-headers: 'ingress-nginx/custom-headers'
```

and custom-headers configmap as following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: custom-headers
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  Host: $host
  X-Real-IP: $remote_addr
  X-Forwarded-For: $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for
```

I cannot find anything useful in the nexus or ingress logs.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I have manage to solve this. We have to expose Nexus with https url instead of http.

I know it's not a solution but
similiar problem found on Nexus 3 community page:

https://community.sonatype.com/t/nexus-3-oss-cant-stay-logged-in-as-admin-cant-see-security-or-any-other-settings/171/10

Comment: Yes its exactly the same problem, when i login over ingress as admin my session is showing as Anonymous.